# jQuery UI Button doesn't work after disabled/enabled from iframe

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, button

I have some code for jQuery, see below:

```
$(function(){
    $('button#submit').button({disabled:true});
    $('button#submit').click(function(){
        console.log('It works!');
    });
    $('a#button-enable').click(function(){
        $('button#submit').button({disabled:false});
    });
});
```

If the link with id `button-enable` isn't clicked, the button must be disabled. After that the button must be enabled and If I click on it, in the console must be outputed the text `It works!`. Why is it not happening?

It happens when I enabled the button from the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(function(){
    $('button#submit').button("option", "disabled", true );
    $('a#button-enable').click(function(){
        $('button#submit').button("option", "disabled", false);
        $('button#submit').click(function(){
            alert('It works!');
        });
    });
});
```

This is from http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#option-disabled

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tmx8t/

Answer (score 0):

I've cleaned up your code a bit and made it work like you described.

```
$(function() {
    var button = $('#submit').button({
        disabled: true
    }).click(function() {
        alert('It Works');
    });
    $('#button-enable').click(function() {
        button.button('enable');
    });
});​
```

Check out the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zero21xxx/RKprq/)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. I solved the problem in the following way:

**parent.html**

```
$(function{
    $('button, input[type="submit"]').button();
    $('button#submit').button('disable');
    $(document).bind('enableButton',function(){
        $('button#submit').button('enable');
    });
    $('button#submit').click(function(){
        //...
    });
});
```

**iframe.html**

```
$(function(){
    //...
    parent.$(parent.document).trigger('enableButton');
});
```